# How to define "Quasifixation" in continuous approximation of finite population?

Tags: evolution, population-dynamics, theoretical-biology, population-biology, population-genetics

**Background**

Many models including the famous very first models derived by [Sir Ronald Fisher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher) in his early career, assume infinite population size. In an infinite population, an allele can rise in frequency (if its fitness is greater than the fitness of its counterpart(s)). This increase follows a logistic curve that never exactly reach a frequency of 1. Therefore, the term fixation does not apply to these model and in consequence the concept of quasifixation has been created.

**Question**

An allele is considered to be quasifixed if it reaches a frequency that is very close to 1. But how close? The decision is obviously arbitrary but when using a *continuous approximation model* in a finite population the question is necessarily raised and a decision needs to be made. **How close should the frequency of an allele be to 1 so that it is considered to be quasifxed?** The answer is probably a function of the population size $N$. What threshold do authors usually use in the theoretical population genetics literature? It would also be nice to have the definition of the author who first coined this term.

Comment: I think there is an answer in here: http://ac.els-cdn.com/0040580972900159/1-s2.0-0040580972900159-main.pdf?_tid=5ae1bc16-8049-11e4-96d2-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1418201507_114d91e34ce366129089c4c4ec02f468

Comment: Or this one might help as well: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1209652/pdf/280.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Garrish and Lensky (1998)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1017067816551) considered reaching fixation when $p > \dfrac{N-1}{N}$, where $p$ is the allele frequency and $N$ the population size.

Note that I ran simulations (unpublished) that well approximated the threshold chosen by [Garrish and Lensky (1998)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1017067816551).

Answer (score 1):

As I haven't found any guideline, I just went with chosing a threshold at $p = 1-\frac{1}{4N}$ for a diploid population. Allele $A$ is therefore considered quasifixed if its frequency $p$ is greater than $1-\frac{1}{4N}$ i.e. the number of occurrences (count) or the other allele is lower than $\frac{1}{2}$.